# CakePHP: REST API Resources with Multiple Levels

Tags: api, cakephp, rest

I am trying to make a REST API with CakePHP but I'm not sure how to approach resources that are more than one level down. For example, I want to make my API so that when a client sends a get request to /users/1/friends.json, a JSON representation of that user's friends is returned. What would be the preferred way to approach this? Should I create a Friendships controller and model and reroute as necessary or perhaps keep everything in the users controller? Just want to know what the standard way of doing this is.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to expose a lot of features like: creating/updating/deleting a user, getting a user, getting all users, etc. you end with a lot of methods in your controller.

I would suggest to use different controllers:

- a `UserController` which owns CRUD methods related to a user, and a method to fetch all users. That would mean 5 methods in this controller;
- a `FriendController` which owns all methods related to a friendship relation: getting user's friends but also creating/removing relations between two users.

I don't know CakePHP but I wrote something about [Symfony2 REST APIs](http://williamdurand.fr/2012/08/02/rest-apis-with-symfony2-the-right-way/) and my use case was a User API. You could pick ideas like how to manage friendship relations between users.